# Add another option for "Full remote"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

In Careers, the "Work remotely" option is great, however some companies use it to mean work remotely part time (like a few days a month).

Obviously part-time remote work vs full-time remote work are very different as a "part-time" remote employee would still be required to be in the same locale as the company, whereas a full-time remote employee could be anyway and would not necessarily have to relocate or travel.

I would like to suggest some more specific options for this field, possibly to capture how much remote work is permitted, or to clarify what a company is specifically looking for in an employee.

Comment: I went ahead and added the [meta-tag:careers] tag and tried to rephrase the question to capture what I think you were asking.  Feel free to roll the edit back and clarify it yourself if you do not feel I captured the point you are trying to make.

Comment: Do such jobs actually exist? Or is this limited to contracting?

Comment: @Stijn **Stack Exchange**, **Github**, **Automattic** (WordPress), **Basecamp**, and **Stripe** are a few companies off the top of my head that offer such positions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Our policy is if an employer checks remote work, it must be for a 100% work from home position. If you find one that isn't, please flag it and we'll edit the listing and inform the client.

Comment: All right, thanks, will do.